# Views ajax not working

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, view

Fresh install

drupal 7.54
jquery_update 7.x-2.7
views 7.x-3.13

Created a normal view, with full pagination, ajax enabled, but when i click on page 2 it gives me this error.

> An error occurred while attempting to process /views/ajax: Cannot set
>   property 'clk' of undefined

Can help me on this? i'm really out of ideas on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: sample url is here:
http://ec2-13-228-27-44.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: I would suggest to try with jQuery version 1.7.1 or something similar. Or you could try with Drupal 7 default jQuery version as well.

Comment: Hi ive tried this version of jQuery also but still doesnt work. i cleared all cache everytime i make changes just to make sure.

Comment: Then i think you should look at this script http://ec2-13-228-27-44.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/js/modules/views/js/ajax_view.js?oq72ti. I don't have the code so i can't test it locally. Its a guess so avoid if you already tried it.

Comment: I had the same error and I fixed it doing a downgrade of jquery-ui.